# Javascript noob: why can't new objects be created from initializers?

Tags: javascript

OK, I really have read everything I can find trying to get a comprehensive understanding of Javascript. I know this can be done using a constructor function, but I'm trying to understand the language enough to know why this happens...

```
PeepClass = { color: "Yellow", shape: "Chick" };

var peepsA = new Object(PeepClass);
var peepsB = new Object(PeepClass);

if ( peepsA == peepsB )
  document.write( "Why wouldn't these be unique instances?" );
```

Why doesn't `new Object(PeepClass)` create unique instances of the `PeepClass` object? Instead, it results in three references to the same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want this:

```
var peepsA = Object.create( PeepClass );
```

Now `peepsA` is a new object which inherits from the object `PeepClass`.

---

Btw when you pass an object into `new Object()`, that same object is returned, ergo, the operation is a no-op.

```
PeepClass === new Object( PeepClass )
```

which means that the notation `new Object( obj )` is meaningless.

Comment: YES..thank you. I haven't seen any examples that present it like that but you're right.

Answer (score 0):

To put it another way, you can initialize an object in two ways:

```
// these are equivalent
var o1 = new Object();
var o2 = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

To quote [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Summary):

> The [Object constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Summary) creates an object wrapper for the given value.
>   If the value is null or undefined, it will create and return an empty
>   object, otherwise, it will return an object of a type that corresponds
>   to the given value.

In other words, when you call `new Object(PeepClass)` what you get back is not an instance of `PeepClass`, but `PeepClass` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Read about new Object([value]) construction in ECMAScript standart. If value is ECMAScript object then it doesn't create a new object, it just return the value.